# How do you phonetically pronounce all of the German note names?

Tags: pronunciation, music

What is the phonetic pronunciation of every note name in German? So, all three iterations of every letter (flat, natural, and sharp) including E#, Cb, etc.

Also, how do you pronounce the German note names “B” and “H”? Is there a German equivalent for the English “B#” (such as “H#”?) and how would that be pronounced phonetically?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. For any questions about how it works, visit the [help].

Comment: I wonder what the German equivalents of quarter tones, i.e. “half sharp” or “half flat”, are.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For those notes that are a letter of the alphabet, e.g. C, A, E, H, B (yes, that one, too) they are pronounced as the letter itself would be. Note, that English *B* is called *H* in German and English *B flat* is German *B*.

A sharp is rendered as the syllable *-is* added to the letter name. So C♯, D♯, E♯ would be *cis, dis, eis*. Note that *eis* is pronounced *e-is*, **not** like *Eis* (ice). *His* is no exception.

A flat is rendered as *es* appended to the letter’s name. The exceptions are A, E and H, which are *As, Es* and *B* respectively.

Double sharp is *-isis* appended to the letter. E.g. *Fisis.* Likewise, double flat is *-eses.* A double flat would be *Ases,* B double flat is *Heses.*

*-Es* is [ɛs], *-is* is [ɪs]; the double forms are twice that.

By themself, ♯ is called *Kreuz* and 𝄪 (probably not displayable) is a *Doppelkreuz*, ♭ is called *B* and ♭♭ is *Doppel-B.* Note the possible confusion that may arise from both ♭ (the sign) and B (the note B♭ in English) sharing the same name.

Comment: We usually say "Kreuz" and "B", which can be a little bit confusing in the latter case because it's also the name of a note. It is usually clear from context, however. "Warum hat der Trompeter Angst vor dem Friedhof? Wegen der vielen Kreuze!" is a popular musician's joke showing usage of the word "Kreuz".

Comment: I think, English _b double flat_ is German _Bes_ (instead of _Heses_), since English _b flat_ is German _B_, isn't it?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach You can think that, but you would be wrong. At least according to my trumpet teacher (who made a point out of it being *Heses* back when I was in high school).

Comment: @Jan Ah ja, you are right: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppel-b: _H hingegen wird zu Heses, nicht etwa zu Bes._

Answer (score 17):

The German sequence of the basic notes (white keys on piano) is: C, D, E, F, G, A, H.

The system is simple. There is no »flat« or »sharp«, just the suffixes »-es« and »-is«. And you have to keep in mind, that the German name of the English B is H. There are five exceptions, they are written in boldface.

I will not talk about enharmonic, I guess you know about it.

- C Note

  - C♭♭: written as »Ceses«, spoken: [t͡sɛsɛs]
  - C♭: »Ces«, [t͡sɛs]
  - C: »C«, [t͡seː]
  - C♯: »Cis«, [t͡sɪs]
  - C♯♯: »Cisis«, [t͡sɪsɪs]
- D Note

  - D♭♭: »Deses«, [dɛsɛs]
  - D♭: »Des«, [dɛs]
  - D: »D«, [deː]
  - D♯: »Dis«, [dɪs]
  - D♯♯: »Disis«, [dɪsɪs]
- E Note

  - **E♭♭: »Eses«, [ɛsɛs]**
  - **E♭: »Es«, [ɛs]**
  - E: »E«, [eː]
  - E♯: »Eis«, [eːɪs] (do not mix up with [aɪ̯s]! Later is the pronunciation of the German word for ice or ice creme, not for the music note)
  - E♯♯: »Eisis«, [eːɪsɪs]
- F Note

  - F♭♭: »Feses«, [fɛsɛs]
  - F♭: »Fes«, [fɛs]
  - F: »F«, [ɛf]
  - F♯: »Fis«, [fɪs]
  - F♯♯: »Fisis«, [fɪsɪs]
- G Note

  - G♭♭: »Geses«, [ɡɛsɛs]
  - G♭: »Ges«, [ɡɛs]
  - G: »G«, [ɡeː]
  - G♯: »Gis«, [ɡɪs]
  - G♯♯: »Gisis«, [ɡɪsɪs]
- A Note

  - **A♭♭: »Asas«, [asas]**
  - **A♭: »As«, [as]**
  - A: »A«, [aː]
  - A♯: »Ais«, [aːɪs]
  - A♯♯: »Aisis«, [aːɪsɪs]
- B Note

  - B♭♭: »Heses«, [hɛsɛs]
  - **B♭: »B«, [beː]**
  - B: »H«, [haː]
  - B♯: »His«, [hɪs]
  - B♯♯: »Hisis«, [hɪsɪs]

### Addendum

The sign ♯ (that looks very similar to the sign #, but is different to it), which is written in a staff before a note's head to mark it as being a halftone higher, is called »Kreuz« ([kʀɔɪ̯ʦ]). This sign can also be part of a staffs key signature.

The sign  before a note's head marks it as two halftones higher and is named »Doppelkreuz« ([ˈdɔpl̩ˌkʀɔɪ̯ʦ]) in German. This sign can not be part of a staffs key signature.

To mark a note as one halftone lower, you use the sign ♭ before a notes head or in the key signature. Since it looks like the letter b (from which it is different!) it is named »B« ([beː]) in German.

To make a note two halftones lower you use the sign  (before a notes head only, never as part of a key signature). It's German name is »Doppel-B« ([ˈdɔpl̩ˌbeː].

To cancel all four of these signs there is the sign ♮ (which also looks similar to #, so be careful with that!). Its German name is »Auflösungszeichen« ([ˈaʊ̯fˌløːzʊŋsˈʦaɪ̯çn̩]]) (verbatim: annulment-sign). But be careful: This sign has barely nothing to do with »resolution« (of a dissonant accord into a consonant accord), with is »Auflösung« in German too.

Comment: As far as I know, in Germany at least, C♭ is pronounced [ʦɛs] (not [ʦes]) and C♯ is pronounced [ʦɪs] (not [ʦis]), etc.