# I need resources to relearn Music Theory in German quickly. Could someone help me out?

Tags: music

I consider myself fairly proficient in Music Theory (in English) and I am trying to migrate to Germany. So with some research, I found that the terms look a lot more different than I expected. There's a random H note for some reason and different names for sharps and flats and the scales. I'm finding it really hard to get reliable and complete information online. I just need to know what most of the common concepts are called in German. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Other than that, this seems to broad and most of it can possibly be answered by a dictionary. Also what is "most common"? If you could somehow make your question more specific (and you're very welcome to split into multiple questions), I think we can give you better answers. Writing a complete English to German music transfer guide is a bit too much to ask, I'm afraid.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26839/1487

Comment: I don't agree with the given closing reason. While on the bottom level there are numerous details (bakunin provides a decent summary in their answer), the question seems to be where to find usable resources, which is definitely answerable. I won't re-open the question on my own, but support the re-open when some approval becomes visible.

Comment: https://www.musiklehre.at/ is a basic music theory website in german language. I think you can take from there what you're missing in terminology

Answer (score 9):

Most terms can be translated with a dictionary. Here are a few pointers about things which probably won't stand out in dictionaries:

**"B"**
What you call "B" is "H" in German, what you call "B-flat" or "Bb" is called "B".

**Halftones**
Halftones are named by adding "-es" (=flat) or "-is" (=sharp). i.e. c-sharp is "cis", d-flat is "des". There are a few exceptions, though: "B-flat" is "B" (instead of "hes"), "a-flat" is "as" (instead of "aes"), and "e-flat" is "es" (instead of "ees"). Note that these postfixes are pronounced as separate syllables: "eis" is "eh-is", not "ice", "ah-is", not "ace". Double flats/sharps have two postfixes added: Fbb="feses", C##="cisis"

**Notes and Rests**
Rests are named like notes of the corresponding length and in German the fraction of the metrum is used: "Viertelpause"/"Viertel(note)" (crotchet rest/quarter note, crotchet), "Achtelpause"/"Achtel(note)" (quaver rest, quaver), etc.. There are no special names for lengths.

**Dynamics and other effects**
are usually named in Italian anyway: "crescendo", "Fermate", "rubato", "Allegro", ...

**Chords and scales**
What you call "major" and "minor" are "Dur" and "Moll". Note, though, that german speaking people (especially Jazzers) call a triad with an added sharped seventh (i.e. c-e-g-h) a "major" (pronounced in English) chord. The normal major triad (c-e-g) would be called "C-Dur". A "C-major-neun" would be "c-e-g-h-d". First and second inversions are sometimes called by their intervals: *Terzsextakkord* is a major chord in first inversion (e-g-c') and *Quartsextakkord* is a major chord in second inversion (g-c'e').

**Intervals**
are called by their Latin names: Prim, Sekund, Terz, Quart(e), Quint(e), Sext(e), Septim(e), Oktave, None, Dezim(e), Undezim(e), Dodezim(e), Tredezim(e). Also notice that we strictly distinguish between "groß-klein" and "vermindert-übermäßig": there is a "große Terz" (c-e) and a "kleine Terz" (c-es), but a "übermäßige Quart" (c-fis, also called *Tritonus*) and a "verminderte Quint" (c-ges).

Comment: Could you elaborate on "übermäßig/vermindert" vs "groß/klein"? I thought I had heard the term "kleine Sekunde" before. Do I understand you right that this was wrong, infact?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: No, groß/klein is something different from übermäßig/vermindert and both exist. I'm afraid, that is more a music than a language issue. A starting question in Music theory and practice can be found [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22525/what-makes-an-interval-perfect).

Comment: @JonathanScholbach groß/klein = major/minor so a "kleine Sekunde"  = "minor second", übermäßig/vermindert = "augmented/diminished". Prime, Fourth and Fifth can only be pure, augmented or diminished the rest could not be pure but major/minor or augmented/diminished. And I have no idea why he bakunin called c-cis a verminderte Sekunde, diminished second as c-cis is an augmented prime (it's the same base note of c), if you would write des (d-flat, enharmonic equivalent = same sound different name on equal temp.) instead of cis then it would be a second, though a minor second not a diminished.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly recommend the [lilypond documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/music-glossary/index.html). Even if not intending to typeset something, this should cover the essential information, especially the sections:

1. Musical terms A-Z
2. Duration names notes and rests
3. Pitch names

Note that in the *Musical terms* section the first line of each keyword page looks harmless, but specifies some known translations in other languages.

Example **concert pitch** (chosen due to completely unrelated translations):

> ES: en Do, tono de concierto, I: intonazione reale, F: tonalité de concert, en ut, D: Kammerton, NL: ?, DK: ?, S: ?, FI: konserttikorkeus.